# Where to allocate one time use class?

Tags: c++, memory-management

Lets consider the following code:

```
void main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
Foo foo;
//at this point I don't need foo any more
//a lot of stuff here
}
```

If I only need `foo` only for short amount of time,isn't it would be better to allocate it on a heap and delete before executing rest of the code?

Comment: Exactly what are you concerned about? Does `Foo` take up a lot of space? Or is it just a case of "I want it to be destroyed as soon as possible"? Or something else?

Comment: Based on your example code, you could write `Foo();` instead of `Foo foo;`, since your code does nothing other than construct it (assuming it has a constructor). If your real code only uses `foo` once then something like `Foo().dostuff();` would still work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, it's better to write an *inner scope*.

```
int main()
{
    {
        Foo foo;
        // use foo
    }
    // more code
}
```

But doing this should be a hint that it might be better to put foo in a completely separate function.

There's no reason to use heap allocation here though. That solution would be worse than the problem.